# Is there an nth term for this system of modular Equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I am interested in the 1st solutions to this set of equations, and wonder if there are any techniques I could use to try and yield an nth term. I'll provide the first few for clarity.

General Equation:

$$3^aN_a + 3^a - 2^a ≡ 2^{2×3^{a-1}} \; mod \; 2^{2×3^{a-1}+1}$$

When a=1

$$ 3N_1 + 1 ≡ 4 \;mod\;8 \;\;\;\;⇒\;\;\;N_1=1$$

When a=2

$$ 9N_2 + 5 ≡ 64 \;mod\; 128 \;\;\;\;⇒\;\;\;N_2=35$$

When a=3

$$ 27N_3 + 19 ≡ 262144 \;mod\; 524288 \;\;\;\;⇒\;\;\;N_3=184471$$

To clarify, I am interested in the sequence: $N_1, N_2, N_3, ...$ and I'm aiming for something of the form: $N_a = \;\;?$

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Nevermind. I've solved it.

Comment: The answer was: $$N_a = (1 - \frac{2^a}{3^a}) × (2^{2×3^{a-1}}-1)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.

$$N_a = \left(1-\dfrac{2^a}{3^a}\right) \times \left(2^{2\times 3^{a-1}}-1 \right)$$